# NullPointerException produced by com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#5

Tags: java, tomcat, nullpointerexception

**Getting NullPointerException**

I am getting NullPointerException

```
Exception in thread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#5" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-8080-150" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "http-8080-148" 
at  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.offer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:273)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler$1.offer(Http11Protocol.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler$1.offer(Http11Protocol.java:554)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:618)
Exception in thread "http-8080-149" 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.offer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:273)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler$1.offer(Http11Protocol.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler$1.offer(Http11Protocol.java:554)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:618)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.offer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:273)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler$1.offer(Http11Protocol.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler$1.offer(Http11Protocol.java:554)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:618)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Nov 26, 2013 19:26:57 -0500 NewRelic 7 WARN: Unexpected exception detecting dead threads: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 Exception in thread "http-8080-178" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.offer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:273)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler$1.offer(Http11Protocol.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler$1.offer(Http11Protocol.java:554)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:618)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Exception in thread "http-8080-179" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.offer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:273)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler$1.offer(Http11Protocol.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler$1.offer(Http11Protocol.java:554)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:618)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can somebody please explain why

```
Exception in thread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#5" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

And

```
  Exception in thread "http-8080-149"   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Are occurring. And why they are producing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space and NullPointerException. How can I overcome these exception.
Please reply if somebody knows about this as these exceptions are occurring on prod server.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is an indicator that you have a memory leak somewhere. Better check your source code and get rid of the out of memory problem.

After that error is thrown, your system is in a quite undefined state. I wouldn't care much about the other exceptions as you have to restart tomcat anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Start the JVM with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`. This will produce a heap dump when the `OutOfMemoryError` is generated.

After that check this out for analyzing the dump:
 http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html

Comment: Hi Ben,Can you please see this post "https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=941839" as it is indicating the NullPointerException due to "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#5" Please see the comment of swaldman.

Comment: Hm if this was already an issue back in 2005, I would be suprised if the change isnt in the new releases yet. I would suggest to give it a try at their forums, since I sadly cant help you any further here..